# Remove closed questions from the review tab

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, review

It seems pointless to have these questions in the reviewed tab, as they have already been closed. There is nothing else to do to them, and they take up space.

Comment: They can still be flagged or voted for deletion, so ostensibly, they still have a place.

Comment: I didn't think that the review tab is for 2nd tier review. I thought it was to give things that tripped some software algorithm a once over.

Comment: I don't get all the downvotes: The OP may be mistaken but the question is OK; there will be more people asking this, so why the pain? Even mistaken questions can be useful. (Even I still don't get the review process completely, maybe someone should slap me in the face with some doc :D...)

Comment: @AloisMahdal, Downvotes on meta mean they think that is it is a bad idea, not that it is a bad question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> There is nothing else to do to them

This is where you are incorrect. These questions are thrown onto the "Review" page, and we can actually edit them, and improve them. Once they are improved, we can flag them to be re-opened by a moderator, or by asking on Meta. I am against taking them out of the review tab.